# regarding Uniform Distribution and sub-Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation

I'm currently studying "High Dimensional Probability" by Vershyynin, and I'm struggling to solve the thm 3.4.6

> **Theorem 3.4.6** (Uniform distribution on the sphere is sub-gaussian) Let $X$ be a random vector uniformly distributed on the Euclidean sphere in $\mathbb R^n$ with center at the origin and radius $\sqrt{n}$:
>  $$X \sim \text{Unif}(\sqrt{n}S^{n-1})$$ Then $X$ is sub-gaussian

Where I'm stuck is the following statement (page 54)

> Thus the event $E := \{\Vert g \Vert_2 \ge \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\}$ is likely; by (2.14), its complement $E^c$ has probability $\mathbb P(E^c) \le 2 e^{−cn}.$

The (2.14) says $\mathbb P(|X| \ge t) \le \text{exp}(-ct^2/\Vert X \Vert_{\psi_2}^2)$ for all sub-Gaussian $X$, but I'm not sure whether $\Vert g \Vert_2$ is sub-Gaussian. Also, I'm not sure whether $\mathbb P(E^c)$ means $\mathbb P (\Vert g \Vert_2 \le \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2})$ or not.

So, I can't understand why the above statement holds due to (2.14).

Any help regarding this question would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I mean…$X$ is compactly supported so it’s sub gaussian

Comment: $\Vert g \Vert_2$ is bounded thus sub-Gaussian, is that what you mean? // Also, what about the P(E^c)? If what I wrote above is correct, how does the $\mathbb P (\Vert g \Vert_2 \le \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}) \le 2e^{cn}$ hold? (which is different from what I know of tail bound)

Comment: @jason1 $\|g\|_2$ is *not* bounded, $X \sim Unif(\sqrt{n}S^{n-1})$ is. What you are using is the subgaussianity of $g$, which gives you the advertised concentration inequality for its norm.

Comment: Then, "$X$ is bounded, as well as sub-gaussian" is another answer? (simple and different approach compared to the textbook, I guess)

Comment: From your book, $X$ is a sub gaussian vector if all its marginals $x^TX$ are subgaussian for all deterministic vectors $x$. Since $X$ is uniformly distributed on a sphere, it is immediate that $x^TX$ is bounded (say by the Schwarz inequality), and thus $X$ is subgaussian vector.

Comment: Ah, I see. Much better solution I guess. Thank you.